replace mathjax extension with Math
I use the MathJax extension on my personal wiki running on my local network (on Ubuntu  box).  I'm thinking of going with the Math extension instead, since the MathJax extension is no longer actively maintained.
Will all my existing MathJax wiki pages need changing (different syntax)?  Or is the Math extension essentially interchangeable with MathJax in that regard?
